# WPF Xaml Designer pointing to different working folder for relative path using image source

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my program I use an icon as image source:

```
<Image Source="\Resources\trash.ico" />
```

The given path is relative to the project file, this works perfectly fine during runtime. However, the WPF designer tries to find the file relative to the VS2017 location and therefore when I'm working on the xaml code I get the following error:

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE%5CResources%5Ctrash.ico'

Where/How do I tell the designer to use the project file location as starting point?

Comment: The icon file should be an assembly resource, i.e. its Build Action should be `Resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the image is located in the same project as your xaml (page, windows, user control...etc.) u can use this :

```xml
<Image Source="./Resources/trash.ico" />
```

Or use Pack Uri specifically:

```xml
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/trash.ico"/>
```

if it is located in a separate project/assembly the use this:

```xml
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/<AssemblyName>;component/Resources/trash.ico"/>
```

replace `<AssemblyName>` with the name of  assembly name where image/icon is added into.

Set the  `Build Action` as `Resource` and `Copy To Output Directory` as `Copy if newer`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, but it doesn't really solve my problem. Also, is there a particular reason why one should use normal backslash, or is it just convention?

Comment: it works on my machine .. try using the `Source="./Resources/trash.ico" ` with the build action set to Resource

Comment: Does the image reside in the same project of your xaml page/window?

Comment: Hmm, weird the build action for these files is set to resource. Not sure, why it isn't working on my machine. The image is included into the project as well...

Comment: OK, silly me. I changed the path to your suggested format. But I had to build the project once for the changes to apply. Works now, thanks for the patience :)